# $A\ne 0:V\to V$ be linear,real vec space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A\ne 0:V\to V$ be linear,real vec space $V$, $\dim V=n$,$V_0=A(V),\dim V_0=k<n$ and for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}, A^2=\lambda A$

Then

1. $\lambda=1$
2. $|\lambda|^n=1$
3. $\lambda$ is the only eigen value of $A$
4. There is a subspace $V_1\subseteq V$ such that $Ax=0\forall x\in V_1$

$4$ is true definitely as I can chose $V_1$ as kernel of $A$ which is non trivial subspace of $V$, well assuming $\lambda\ne 0$ we get charpoly for $A$ is $x(x-\lambda)=0$ so $0,\lambda$ are eigen value  with some multiplicity so $3$ is false, I have no idea about $1$ and $2$, could any one tell me?

Comment: Consider the matrix $A$ with 1 in the upper right entry, 0 otherwise. Then $A^2=0=0A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both (1) and (2) are not true.
We'll choose:

$n=2 $

$ A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) $

$ V = Sp\left\{(1,0),(0,1) \right\} $

then:

$ \dim(V)=2 $

$ \dim(AV)=1<2 $ (easy multiply)

and we get:
$ A^{2}=2A $. Therefor, those are falses.